# Merge and Aggregate data in Groovy

Tags: groovy, group-by, sum, aggregate

I was wondering what the best way to aggregate this data would be in Groovy?

Lets say I have the following data:

```
[
   [id: 1, name: bob, age:20, numberOfPackages: 10, numberOfPurchases:20 ],
   [id: 1, name: bob, age:20, numberOfPackages: 5, numberOfPurchases:6 ],
   [id: 2, name: Rob, age:22, numberOfPackages: 3, numberOfPurchases:5 ],
]
```

and I want to transform it to the following (merge *id*/*name*/*age* but sum *price*/*number* of purchases per *id*):

```
[
   [id: 1, name: bob, age:20, numberOfPackages: 15, numberOfPurchases:26 ],
   [id: 2, name: Rob, age:22, numberOfPackages: 3, numberOfPurchases:5 ],
]
```

Comment: You want to sum the prices? Not sum the price * number of purchases for each row?

Comment: If any of the answers meets your expectations please accept it.

Comment: I wanted to sum the prices. I've edited the example to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Summing the prices, and the number of purchases separately makes little sense, do you mean:

```
def data = [
    [id: 1, name: 'bob', age:20, price: 10, numberOfPurchases:20],
    [id: 1, name: 'bob', age:20, price:  5, numberOfPurchases:6],
    [id: 2, name: 'rob', age:22, price:  3, numberOfPurchases:5]
]

data.groupBy { [id:it.id, name:it.name, age:it.age] }.collect { k, v ->
    [id:k.id,
     name:k.name,
     age:k.age,
     spend:v.collect { it.price * it.numberOfPurchases }.sum()]
}
```

Which gives:

```
[
    [id:1, name:'bob', age:20, spend:230],
    [id:2, name:'rob', age:22, spend:15]
]
```

Comment: Good point! The values I just used for this however were dummy example values, and this does in fact make more sense with the actual real-life case scenario. I will edit my question to use some better dummy values.

Answer (score 1):

It may be e.g.:

```
def data = [
    [id: 1, name: 'bob', age:20, price: 10, numberOfPurchases:20 ],
    [id: 1, name: 'bob', age:20, price: 5, numberOfPurchases:6 ],
    [id: 2, name: 'rob', age:22, price: 3, numberOfPurchases:5 ],
]

data.groupBy { it.id }.collectEntries { 
    [
        (it.key): [
            name: it.value.name.first(), 
            age: it.value.first(), 
            price: it.value.sum { it.price },
            numberOfPurchases: it.value.sum { it.numberOfPurchases },
        ]
    ] 
 }
```